# Hovering link over tab in navigation bar does not cover entirely

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar and Im trying to create a tabbed navigation.

The hover background color filled up the whole tabs(about,login/register and cart) when hovering over it when I used text instead of images on the navigation bar.

I added a cart icon image on the tabbed navigation for cart to replace the cart text and the hover is working by covering the entire area of the cart tab which is what I wanted. 
[cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k5Tn.png)

However I can't seem to get the hover background color to fill these tabs(about and login/register) and there are spaces at the bottom.
[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvynh.png)

These are the html and css codes for the navigation bar

HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="main"><a href="cart.php" target="_blank"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2u43au0.png" border="0" width="20" height="20"/></a>    </li>
    <li class="main"><a href="login.php">Login/Register</a></li>
    <li class="main"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.main {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -10px -40px;
  width: 1280px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 230px;
}

li.main {
  float: right;
}

li.main a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
}

li.main a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the `hover`, does it contain the entire height or width of it's parent. Post your code so we can locate where the issue is from.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @WhiteHox @ SaschaM78 sorry, i accidentally posted it without typing finish. I posted my codes already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must indicate a height to your `a` items, so it adjust to the navigation height, in this case the biggest element is the image with a height of 20px, so it will look like this:

```
li.main a {
  height: 20px; /* The navigation height */
}
```

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/fv2jdazp/

Comment: I added a height of 50px and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using `height: auto` for `ul.main`. if not
Change height to `height: 50px` and `li.main a padding: 17px 16px` but the main problem in your code is not setting a `height` for your `a` items